# Float value using case in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, floating-point, case

I have this code and I'm trying to compare `[Dis]` to `[Estimator]` which is a variable I am adding:

```
SELECT 
    [Id],
    [Sym],
    [Month],
    [Dis],
    Estimator =  4/count(Id) over (partition by Sym, Month)
FROM 
    [RegularPayResultsYearly]
```

Again, I'm trying to compare `Dis` to `Estimator`.

For example, the `count(Id) over (partition by Sym, [Month])` is 12091 observations.

The problem : while the `Dis` column is a `float` type (example values : 
8.2944916060179E-06, 9.07691249104339E-05) it seems that the

```
4/count(Id) over (partition by Sym, [Month])  as cnt
```

which is 3.308245802663138e-4 cannot go further than zero and it showing me 
Estimator = 0.

Any way to change that?

Thanks.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the non-standard syntax

Comment: not sure but did you try to write: 4.0/count(Id) instead of 4/count(Id)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot compare floating point times using equality -- and be consistently accurate.  You can have two solutions.  One is to take the absolute value of the difference and call it 0 if it is less than some (arbitrary) threshold:

```
SELECT . . .,
       (CASE WHEN ABS(Dis) - 4/count(Id) over (partition by Sym, Month)) < 0.001
             THEN 'EQUAL'
             ELSE 'NOTEQUAL'
        END)
FROM RegularPayResultsYearly
```

The second is to use decimal/numeric rather than float:

```
SELECT . . .,
       (CASE WHEN CAST(Dis, DECIMAL(10, 3)) =
                  CAST(4.0/count(Id) over (partition by Sym, Month) AS DCIMAL(10, 3) = 0
             THEN 'EQUAL'
             ELSE 'NOTEQUAL'
        END)
FROM RegularPayResultsYearly
```

Do note that the expression `4/COUNT(ID) OVER (PARTITiON BY Sym, Month)` is going to return an integer (and probably 0 at that).  SQL Server does integer division when both operands are integers.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, IN ELSE, what if I dont want to pass 'NOTEQUAL' and pass a NULL Value of Float

```
    SELECT . . .,
       (CASE WHEN CAST(Dis, DECIMAL(10, 3)) =
                  CAST(4.0/count(Id) over (partition by Sym, Month) AS DCIMAL(10, 3) = 0
             THEN 'EQUAL'
             ELSE 'NOTEQUAL'
        END)
FROM RegularPayResultsYearly
```